# Code inside dictionary ran without being called

Tags: python

I'm creating a function for logging, and used a dictionary to determine the log level. However, the value(code) inside the dictionary ran without calling it.

```
def debug(level = 0, text = ''):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    Formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', datefmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    fileLog = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
    fileLog.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fileLog.setFormatter(Formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fileLog)
    streamLog = logging.StreamHandler()
    streamLog.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    streamLog.setFormatter(Formatter)
    logger.addHandler(streamLog)
    log = str(sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name + "  " + text)
    logLevel = {
        0: logger.debug(log),
        1: logger.info(log),
        2: logger.warning(log),
        3: logger.error(log),
        4: logger.critical(log)
    }
    logLevel.get(level, None)

def test():
    debug(0, "MESSAGE")
```

How do i solve this?

Comment: You literally call all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you added "()" to `logger.debug` you told python you want to store the returned result of that function to the dict. It looks like you want to store a function then call it later. If that's the case do something like this.

```
logLevel = {
        0: logger.debug,
        1: logger.info,
        2: logger.warning,
        3: logger.error,
        4: logger.critical
}
logLevel.get(level, None)(log)
```

Now you store the reference to the function `logger.debug` then you retrieve it from the dict and then call it.

**Be warned since your default return from `get` is `None` this will throw an error if it isn't in the dict.**

Answer (score 1):

The values of the dictionary must be evaluated before the dictionary can be created. There's no way around that.

What you can do though is wrap the values in a function, then call that function later:

```
logLevel = {
    0: lambda: logger.debug(log),
    1: lambda: logger.info(log),
    2: lambda: logger.warning(log),
    3: lambda: logger.error(log),
    4: lambda: logger.critical(log)
}

log_f = logLevel[1]
log_f()  # Will call the "lambda: logger.info(log)" function.
```

The values are still being evaluated, but now it's the function that's evaluated, and not the code that it contains.

This can also be achieved by using `functools.partial`

```
from functools import partial

logLevel = {
    0: partial(logger.debug, log),
    1: partial(logger.info, log),
    2: partial(logger.warning, log),
    3: partial(logger.error, log),
    4: partial(logger.critical, log)
}

log_f = logLevel[1]
log_f()
```

The key though is the need to delay execution, and a function wrapper is the easiest (but not necessarily the only option) to achieve that.